# Ботнет для Android

Tags: android, безопасность

Я изучаю Java + Android. И наткнулся на статью о ботнетах для Android. И мне стало интересно, какие же в этой системе уязвимости. Казалось бы, в основе Android лежит Linux. В описание написано, что это многопользовательская ОС, где каждое приложение - это отдельный юзер, который имеет ID. Причем это ID неизвестно в приложении. Если создать какой-нибудь файл (из приложения), то права доступа будут только для этого ID. Я почти незнаком с системой Linux, и поэтому мне интересно, какие же уязвимости там есть. И какими пользуются злоумышленники, создающие вредоносные программы для Android. Я так предполагаю, они это пишут не на Java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самая простая уязвимость -приложение рассылает платные смс или просто рассылает спам. Главное запросить привелегии и надеятся, что пользователь не заметит.

Следующая уязвимость - собрать побольше персональных данных и отправить кому нужно на сохранение.

В целом, если не использовать рутованые устройства и смотреть на то, какие привелегии запрашивает приложение, можно отсекать 99% вирусов и ботов.

Comment: От рутованности устройства, строго говоря, ситуация не зависит — как безопасность GNU/Linux-системы не зависит от наличия sudo.

Если root на устройстве получается без использования nvflash и подобных, а получается за счет эксплойтов (Gingerbreak, Honeybomb и т.п.), то приложение, если захочет, то все равно получит полный контроль. Т.е., например, на A500 крутится (с привелегиями root) демон cmd_server, слушающий FIFO, доступный на запись всем (0777). И до последнего времени этот сервер выполнял команду в духе `sh -c "echo %s > /sys/blah"`, т.е. имел явную shell injection. Думаю, суть ясна.

Comment: Есть приложения наподобие файловых менеджеров для Android. Получается, они написаны небезопасно?

Comment: В неумелых руках (или особо умелых) практически любой файловый менеджер может стать причиной превращения телефона в кирпич.